# VSCode is appending unsupported text encoding on file save

Tags: visual-studio-code

Not sure what's up with VSCode after updating to Version 1.10.2 VSCode is appending weird characters automatically after saving the file.

[image: Weird Characters]

If I try to open the file with VSCode I get the following error.

`The file will not be displayed in the editor because it is either binary, very large or uses an unsupported text encoding.`

[image: Error Message]

This only happens sometimes, not on every single save to disk action.

I'm using a SAMBA share, not sure if that has something to do with it.

I'm on MAC 10.12.3

** Update 3/16/17 **
Here is a gif of how it's happening.

[image: Weird Characters]